# Create a weighted feeder in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a few .csv files I want to use for the same data in Gatling. Each of these files has a certain number of ID's that I want to be accessed fairly equally. I don't want to put them all in the same file because the .csv files are generated from SQL queries and, while I may have a lot of IDs in one file, I only have a few in another. What's important to me is that I have a random sample from each of my files and a way to specify the distribution.

I found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533162/gatling-dynamic-feed-selection?rq=1) of how to do this but I'm having trouble applying it in my case. Here is the code I have so far. I try to both 1) print out the value from the feeder in the session and 2) try to use the value from the feeder in a get request. Both attempts fail with various errors which I detail below:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import util.Random

class FeederTest extends Simulation {

  //headers...

  val userCreds = csv("user_creds.csv")

  val sample1 = csv("sample1.csv")

  val sample2 = csv("sample2.csv")

  def randFeed(): String = {
    val foo = Random.nextInt(2)
    var retval = ""
    if (foo == 0) retval = "file1"
    if (foo == 1) retval = "file2"
    return retval
  }

  val scn = scenario("feeder test")
    .repeat(1) {
      feed(userCreds)
        .doSwitch(randFeed)(
          "file1" -> feed(sample1),
          "file2" -> feed(sample2)
        )  
        .exec(http("request - login")
          .post("<URL>")
          .headers(headers_login)
          .formParam("email", "${username}")
          .formParam("password", "<not telling>"))
        .exec(session => {
           println(session)
           println(session("first").as[String])
           session})
        .exec(http("goto_url")
          .get("<my url>/${first}"))

        }
  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

This is the error I get when I attempt to printout the feeder value in the session (as in the above code using `session(<value>).as[String]`):

```
[ERROR] [03/13/2015 10:22:38.221] [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://GatlingSystem/user/sessionHook-2] key not found: first                                                                              
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: first                                                         
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)                                                    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)                                                  
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)                                             
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)                                                    
        at io.gatling.core.session.SessionAttribute.as(Session.scala:40)                                       
        at FeederTest$$anonfun$2.apply(feeder_test.scala:81)                                                   
        at FeederTest$$anonfun$2.apply(feeder_test.scala:79)                                                   
        at io.gatling.core.action.SessionHook.executeOrFail(SessionHook.scala:35)                              
        at io.gatling.core.action.Failable$class.execute(Actions.scala:71)                                     
        at io.gatling.core.action.SessionHook.execute(SessionHook.scala:28)                                    
        at io.gatling.core.action.Action$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Actions.scala:29)                      
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)                                 
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)                                               
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:22)                                    
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)                                            
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)                                                    
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)    
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)                                                        
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)                                                       
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)                                
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)                    
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)                            
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I have also tried just using the EL expression `${first}` in the session. All this does is print out the string `${first}`. Similarly in the last `.get` line I get an error saying "No attribute named 'first' is defined.

The CSV files I'm currently using just have two columns of first and last in them like so:

```
sample1.csv:
first, last
george, bush
bill, clinton
barak, obama

sample2.csv:
first, last
super, man
aqua, man
bat, man
```

I'm using Gatling 2.1.4.

Comment: After correcting the typo, I realized I still had a problem (sorry for the incorrect marking). It appears my problem is that either you can't access the feeder data inside of session or I'm using the wrong syntax for it. When I debug the session output I don't see any of the feeder data there. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do by printing this in the session?

Comment: I've never used feeders, but from the documentation, I see two possible problems - 1. `randFeed` returns either "foo" or "bar" but you're mapping with "file1" and "file2", so is anything being loaded?  2. The examples for feeders I see don't show accessing fed data with `session(varname)` but rather "${varname}".

Comment: The "foo", "bar" in `randFeed` was a cut paste mistake which I have fixed. As for using `"${varname}"`, whenever I use that, it just prints out `${first}`. I don't believe you can use EL expressions inside session - I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doSwitch` takes an `Expression[Any]`, which is a type alias for `Session => Validation[Any]`. Gatling has an implicit conversion that let you pass a static value instead, see [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/expression_el.html#expression).

Which is exactly what you do. Even if `randFeed` is a def, it still doesn't return a function, but a String.

As you want randFeed to be called every time a virtual user pass through this step, you have to wrap the `randFeed` inside a function, even if you don't use the Session input parameter.

```
doSwitch(_ => randFeed)
```

Then, your randFeed is both ugly (no offense) and inefficient (Random is synchronized):

```
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
def randFeed(): String =
  ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2) match {
    case 0 => "file1"
    case 1 => "file2"
  }
```

Comment: Stephane - thanks so much for answering my question. This works for me. I had to make the following minor modifications for anyone else implementing this:  
1) import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
2) enclose the randFeed() function in extra {}'s which weren't in your answer above
I'm going to make sure this completely resolves all my issues before I accept your answer which should be in the next week.

Comment: You don't need to enclose with {}, as there's only one operation.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used feeders, but from the documentation, I see two possible problems:

1. `randFeed` returns either "foo" or "bar" but you're mapping with "file1" and "file2", so is anything being loaded? (The [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/general/scenario.html) says "If no switch is selected, the switch is bypassed.")
2. The [examples for feeders](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/advanced_tutorial.html#step-03-use-dynamic-data-with-feeders-and-checks) I see don't show accessing fed data with `session(varname)` but rather `"${varname}"`.

Comment: That's why I'm not brave enough to leave my IDE behind!

Comment: I'm going to mark this as an unaccepted answer - sorry.  I've found that I have more problems here and I can't post the question again.

Comment: The "foo", "bar" in randFeed was a cut paste mistake which I have fixed. As for using "${varname}", whenever I use that, it just prints out ${first}. I don't believe you can use EL expressions inside session - I may be wrong.

Comment: My point was that you don't use `session()` at all - the examples don't show it being used.

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully highlight more clearly what the problem is. @soong - I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. There is something wrong with the way that I am calling the feed method in my .doSwitch statement that prevents the variables from being defined.